# "Off-topic" but no reason stated?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/433161/hypernym-for-sender-and-recipient-in-terms-of-a-shipment) was classed as "off-topic" but no reason was stated and therefore the OP had no chance to edit and improve.

I'm not taking sides and not criticising - I am just asking if this is usual as I do not remember seeing it before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is in the associated [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/433161/hypernym-for-sender-and-recipient-in-terms-of-a-shipment#comment1040105_433161):

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our Help Center says that picking names for computer software thingies is out of scope for our site. – tchrist♦